# Why is MultivaluedMap<String, String> params coming empty on a method annotaded with @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded") in Resteasy?

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy

Is any RestayEasy specific configuration needed to get the MultivaluedMap filled with all form parameters?

I have many webservices working fine using RestEasy. But for the first time I  need to be able to iterate over all form parameters submitted in order to  handle unpredictable form parameters.
trying with the following code is giving me an empty Map.

```
@POST
@Path("/")
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public Response post(MultivaluedMap<String, String> params) {
    System.out.println("post " );
    System.out.println("formParams " + params);

}



I am using RestEasy 3.1.4 with the following maven dependencies :

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Trey using the `@FormDataMultiPart("myform")` annotation

Comment: Just to make it clear, is it means that you have iterated over the multi valued map using for each loop??